# PHPMailer: Attach a file located on server

Tags: php, attachment, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an (up to 4) attachments using PHPMailer.  The files are on my server.

This is how my script works:

User sees a job or resume and contacts them by using the contact form.  The contact form stores the data along with the attachments on the server.  We will then review the message filtering out spams/scams.  If the message is genuine then we will send the message through.

I have the information stored on the server and Im able to send that information via email however the attachments are not sending.

Here is the code used to send the mail:

```
if ($_GET['status'] == 'approve') {

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    dbconnect($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $db.mail WHERE id = $id";
    $results=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $id         = $row["id"];
    $to         = $row["to"];
    $from       = $row["from"];
    $subject    = $row["subject"];
    $message    = $row["message"];
    $file1      = $row["file1"];
    $file2      = $row["file2"];
    $file3      = $row["file3"];
    $file4      = $row["file4"];


    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET `status` =  '1', `approvedtime` =  NOW() WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'])
        or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: mail.php");

        // PHPMailer - Start
        $email = new PHPMailer();
        $email->setLanguage('ja');
        $email->From      = $from;
        $email->FromName  = 'MySite.com';
        $email->Subject   = $subject;
        $email->Body      = $message;
        $email->addAddress($to);


        if (!empty($file1)) {
            $file1 = 'upload/'.$file1;
            $email->AddAttachment($file1);
        }
        if (!empty($file2)) {
            $file2 = 'upload/'.$file2;
            $email->AddAttachment($file2);
        }
        if (!empty($file3)) {
            $file3 = 'upload/'.$file3;
            $email->AddAttachment($file3);
        }
        if (!empty($file4)) {
            $file4 = 'upload/'.$file4;
            $email->AddAttachment($file4);
        }


        return $email->Send();
        // PHPMailer - Start
    }

} elseif ($_GET['status'] == 'reject') {

    dbconnect($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET `status` =  '2', `approvedtime` =  NOW() WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'])
        or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: mail.php");
    }
```

Why are the attachments not sending? Am I missing a step in my code or have something incorrect?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your missing something ... the question

Comment: "I have the information stored on the server and Im able to send that information via email however the attachments are not sending."  Sorry, I should have made it more clear. ;-)  Why are the attachments not sending?  Am I missing a step in my code or have something incorrect?  Thanks.

Comment: silly me, i was looking for a question mark.

Comment: My mistake.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If a physical file doesn't exist on your server, then it won't find it and in return not attach it. What does your data in your rows look like?

Comment: When I queried the DB for files 1 - 4 it returned this: File1: 531c8df62e7361.jpeg
File2: 531c8df62e7363.jpeg
File3: 531c8df62e7362.jpeg
File4: 531c8df62e7364.jpg

Comment: and those files exist in `upload/` be sure about the file path

Comment: You may want to insert a code line like this just before the attachment:
if (! file_exists($file1)) die("file $file1 not there");

Comment: and those files exist in upload/ be sure about the file path – Dagon  Yes, I did a full path/file output, copied/pasted and the file was found.

Comment: It's time to use `var_dump();` on your variables then and use [`if_exists()`](http://www.php.net/file_exists) instead of `if (!empty($file1))` --- You may also need to use the full `http://` path or `/upload/` to go straight to the root if you're running your code other than from your root.

Comment: Here is my var_dump for the files: `code string(53) "http://domain.com/upload/531c8df62e7361.jpeg" string(53) "http://domain.com/upload/531c8df62e7363.jpeg" string(53) "http://domain.com/upload/531c8df62e7362.jpeg" string(52) "http://domain.com/upload/531c8df62e7364.jpg" `

Comment: I don't know what it could be; am baffled.

Comment: When I do a check like this `code if (!file_exists($file1)) {echo "File1;"} if (file_exists($file2)) {echo "File2;"} ` Both $file1 and $file2 are there but the output is "File1" telling me that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: It's `{echo $file1;}` and not `{echo "File1;"}`

Comment: I feel embarrassed to say but it was a file location problem in the end.  Thanks for your help everyone!